# How Can I Simplify Classes That Do Similar Things

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on a project where I call an external API.  I want to cache the API responses for a certain amount of time and have created a 5 classes that all do practically the same thing: get data from cache or if the cache doesn't have data, get data from the API.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to simply this code.

Class:

```
using DataCreator.Foo.Api;
using DataCreator.Foo.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataCreator.Foo.DataProvider
{
    public class PerformanceStatusDataProvider
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;

        public PerformanceStatusDataProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            memoryCache = serviceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
        }

        public List<PerformanceStatus> GetPerformanceStatuses()
        {
            return memoryCache.GetOrCreate("performance_status", cacheEntry =>
            {
                cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                return FooApi.Instance.GetPerformanceStatuses();

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your DataProviders follow a similar syntax, it should be quite easy with generics:

```
public List<T> GetData<T>(string cacheKey, Func<List<T>> retrieveDataFromApi)
{
    return memoryCache.GetOrCreate(cacheKey, cacheEntry =>
    {
        cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

        return retrieveDataFromApi();
    });
}
```

You'd call this using something like:

```
GenericDataProvider.GetData("performance_status", FooApi.Instance.GetPerformanceStatuses);
```

Small details: you're calling an API and you're not using `async/await` (you most definitively should) and `FooApi.Instance` is a code smell, you're 50% using Dependency Injection and 50% hard-coding dependencies.

Comment: This is great, thanks! One quick question, this way, every caller will need to know the cache key and the method to get the data from the api. How can we solve that?

Comment: @my_overflowed_stack There are many ways to solve that: using static class with constants for the keys, using Enums, having a private dictionary with map type name => cache key, etc, you could even keep all data providers that internally call this generic one if you wished. What you end up going with is up to you and your needs